# Trouble converting back from int to DateTime

Tags: android, datetime, sqlite

I am returning data from a sqlite3 database the some else wrote.  I am trying to retrieve the date and time.  To store it into the db I converted the date and time into one int. using this line

```
  int currentTime=(int) ((newTime).toMillis(true) / 1000);
```

I am able to retrieve the data as an int, but cannot figure out how to convert the number back into a 
date and time.  Currently the db returns int 13333380180, I am trying to convert it to today's date and time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
long yourmilliseconds = 13333380180;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm");

Date resultdate = new Date(yourmilliseconds);
System.out.println(sdf.format(resultdate));
```

Use the above code to convert

Comment: You have to multiply the seconds by 1000, because currentTime is toMillis divided by 1000.

Comment: new Date(13333380180) results in Thu Jun 04 08:43:00 CET 1970, new Date(13333380180000) results in Wed Jul 08 14:43:00 CEST 2392, look both very strange.

Comment: It is converting all times to Jan 16, 1970 02:23.

Comment: what must be the date according to your expectations

Comment: Thanks, converted the int to a long, multiplied it by 1000 and now it works

Answer (score 0):

The number you're receiving is the number of milliseconds that have passed since January 1st, 1970. It's a standard, consistent way of representing a date & time on a number of platforms.

Although the value is an integer in SQLite, SQLite integers can be up to 64 bits. So, the value being returned to you should be treated as a `long` in Java. You can convert it to a Java `Date` object in a straightforward fashion: `new Date(currentTime)`.